# Empty array category , why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was wondering why I get an empty array despite I've used setCategory but If I print (res.data.category), there are data inside this.

If you know anything about this, Thanks for your help.

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);


    var listItems = '';
    useEffect(() => {

axios.get(`/api/getCategory`).then(res => {

if (res.data.status === 200) {
                    setCategory(res.data.category);
                    console.log(res.data.category);

                }
            });
     
    }, []);
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Other than the initial state, where is there an empty array?

Comment: It's category If I print this It looks empty. I need to set the data into category because I'm planning to use this to render in html later.

Comment: Where are you printing `category`? Right after enqueueing the state update?

Comment: yes, after setCategory();

Comment: I see. React state updates are not immediately processed, they are enqueued and asynchronously processed. If you want to log state updates use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the value you want to log.